# how to implement timeline (real-time - like twitter's) using tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, timeline

guys,
I want to implement a website, which need the function of timeline (just like twitter's). Now I'm using Tornado as the web framework. How can I get it? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2011/mar/14/twitter-developers-client-warning

Answer (score 1):

The real time element of [the twitter "timeline"](http://support.twitter.com/entries/164083-what-is-a-timeline) is almost certainly a load of AJAX which periodically goes back to the server, requests any new posts and then updates the page with the results.

Google has [many suggestions](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ajax+page+updates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) on how to update a page using AJAX. Get reading :-)